# Using Regex to find and replace email addresses

Tags: python

New to Python and would like to use it with Regex to work with a list of 5k+ email addresses. I need to change the encapsulate each address with either quotes. I am using `\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b` to identify each email address. How would I replace the current entry of user@email.com to "user@email.com" adding quotes around the each of the 5k email addresses?

Comment: [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) module and using back-reference like this:

```
>>> a = "this is email: someone@mail.com and this one is another email foo@bar.com"
>>> re.sub('([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,})', r'"\1"', a)

'this is email: "someone@mail.com" and this one is another email "foo@bar.com"'
```

**UPDATE**: If you have a file that want to replace emails in each line of it you can use `readlines()` like this:

```
import re

with open("email.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

new_lines = []
for line in lines:
    new_lines.append(re.sub('([A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,})', r'"\1"', line))

with open("email-new.txt", "w") as file:
    file.writelines(new_lines)
```

email.txt:

```
this is test@something.com and another email here foo@bar.com
another email abc@bcd.com
still remaining someone@something.com
```

email-new.txt (after running the code):

```
this is "test@something.com" and another email here "foo@bar.com"
another email "abc@bcd.com"
still remaining "someone@something.com"
```

Comment: I forgot to mention I have Text file stored locally with each email address on separate lines that I need to load. So basically I'm doing a read and replace to the file.

Comment: thank you that worked perfectly. I just have one more question and I'll be out of your hair. How would I prepend each address with "mail=". I was just told this will be used for LDAP search for file format import.

Comment: @the1fan just change `r'"\1"'` to `r'mail="\1"'` in line starts with `new_lines.append(re.sub...`

Comment: Thank you for your help